# Cant get inputs length with ng-pattern min width

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Cant get input length when i use ng-pattern for input . The number of length visible after 4th element .

```
<label ng-class="username.length ? 'focused': ''"> LabelText </label>
<input type='text'ng-model='username' ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]{4,16}$/" />"
```

Comment: Please improve your question. It's unclear what you are asking and what you have tried right now to "get the input length" you talking about.

Comment: @lin I want to detect inputs test length , but in this case i cant detect it ( its not undefined only after 4rd character)

Comment: Your `regex` is working well. It does check for  `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `{4,16}`. Also `length` is working ->  http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9807/ Please descripe your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is some kind of dizzying. :) Thats way some users voted you down. Your code you provided works well if your change your regex declaration from `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]{4,16}$/` into `^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]{4,16}$`. Please compare your codes with the following working example.

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9811/) of what you are trying to achieve.

#### View with testing JavaScript regex:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="form">
    <label for="regex">Set a pattern (regex string): </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="regex" id="regex" />
    <br>
    <label for="input">This input is restricted by the current pattern: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-class="model.length ? 'error': ''" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="regex" /><br>
    <hr>
    input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
    model = <code>Model length: {{model.length}}</code>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]{4,16}$';
}]);
```

Comment: Thansk for answer :) its really work !
But input should consist of min 4  and max 16 ,but in this fiddle is not work

Comment: Good! Hint: `model` will be an empty string if `ngPattern` does not match.